# Dynamic table on VF page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, apex, html

I have a requirement in which I have to display records of object as Table. 
In which column header values will be dynamically taken from Records fields values which need to populate in respective cells.
Problem I am facing here is columns (A 1,A2 inside A)in side columns with Row Header(Parameter1,2,3) as shown in image.
Can anyone help with design part?

[image: Image for requirement calrity]

Comment: Can you please be more specific and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? What do you mean by the "design part"?

Comment: Should I go with <Table> tag or <apex:DataTable> tag

Comment: You would have more control over the standard HTML output if you go with <table>.

Comment: I have created table using tag , In that table Column Header values are coming dynamically from Apex class as List. while displaying it on vf page I am using tag to populate the values of Column headers.

Problem: column header are not placed side by side. Rather new row is automatically populated . Due to view column layout is geting disturbed. Code: <tr>
<th></th>          
<apex:repeat value="{!lstToshowRiskEvents}" var="events" > 
<th><center>{!events}</center></th>
</apex:repeat>
</tr>